# Advice on meaningful URL formats for an MVC application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to decide on meaningful URLs for my application (to track application releases).  The site is pretty simple: My first screen lists applications.  Clicking on an application takes you to releases for that application.  Clicking on a release then takes you to notes for that release.

So, I was initially thinking:

```
~/applications
~/releases?applicationid=34
~/notes?releaseid=290
```

I was also thinking of this:

```
~/applications
~/application-name/releases
~/application-name/release-number/notes
```

The challenge with the latter approach is that application-name can have spaces which means I have to convert to hyphens when preparing the URL and then convert back to spaces when reading the URL.

Generally speaking, which style is recommended?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking which is better for SEO?  If so then your asking on the wrong site.  ;)

Comment: Yes and no--I wanted to stick to the SEO best practices, but this app is in a corporate environment, so SEO is not important.

Comment: So then you are asking a subjective question unless there are usability concerns.

Comment: I think both formats are usable.  But I want to find out if one is considered more readable than the other.

Comment: @Prabhu - Thats still pretty subjective unless somebody cites a study.

Comment: @jfar - oh ok...so there is no particular best practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

How you set this up is really just personal preference in your situation. There are a couple situations that I can think of where you might want to think carefully about this, web services and SEO friendly URLS.